# How to test swt wizard GUI with jmeter

Tags: eclipse, jmeter, swt, jobs

---

public class CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO extends WizardPage  {

```
class MedianBestChart {

    JFreeChart             chart;
    ChartComposite         innerChartComposite;
    java.awt.Color         awtRedColor;
    Shape                  downTriangleShap;
    Shape                  upTriangleShape;
    XYPlot                 plot;
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer;
    XYSeries               bestValsSeries;
    XYSeries               medianValsSeries;
    XYSeries               diffValsSeries;
    XYSeriesCollection     dataset;

    MedianBestChart(String title, String yAxisText) {

        this.bestValsSeries = new XYSeries("Best candidate");
        this.medianValsSeries = new XYSeries("Median");
        this.diffValsSeries = new XYSeries("Diff");

        this.dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        this.dataset.addSeries(this.bestValsSeries);
        this.dataset.addSeries(this.medianValsSeries);
        this.dataset.addSeries(this.diffValsSeries);

        this.awtRedColor = SWTUtils.toAwtColor(SWTResourceManager
                .getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        this.downTriangleShap = ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(3);
        this.upTriangleShape = ShapeUtilities.createUpTriangle(3);

        this.chart = createChart(title, yAxisText);

        this.innerChartComposite = new ChartComposite(
                CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO.this.chartParentComposite,
                SWT.FILL, this.chart, true);

        // grid data for the composite;
        final GridData chartCompositeGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, // horizontalAlignment;
                SWT.FILL, // verticalAlignment;
                true, // grabExcessHorizontalSpace;
                true); // grabExcessVerticalSpace;

        chartCompositeGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        chartCompositeGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;

        this.innerChartComposite.setLayoutData(chartCompositeGridData);
        this.innerChartComposite.setRangeZoomable(false);
        this.innerChartComposite.setDomainZoomable(false);
        this.innerChartComposite.setVisible(true);

        this.chart.setBorderVisible(false);

        CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO.this.chartParentComposite
        .layout(true);
    }

    JFreeChart createChart(String title, String yAxisText) {

        // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title,
                "Nr. candidates", // x
                // axis
                // label
                yAxisText, // y axis label
                this.dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, // include legend
                false, // tooltips
                false // urls
                );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(SWTUtils.toAwtColor(Display.getDefault()
                .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND)));

        Font titleFontTmp = chart.getTitle().getFont();
        Font chartTitleFont = new Font("Plot title font",
                titleFontTmp.getStyle(), titleFontTmp.getSize() - 6);

        chart.getTitle().setFont(chartTitleFont);

        this.plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        this.plot.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);
        this.plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(java.awt.Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(java.awt.Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        this.renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8963966491796723264L;

            @Override
            public LegendItem getLegendItem(int datasetIndex, int series) {
                if (series != 2) {
                    return super.getLegendItem(datasetIndex, series);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

        };

        this.renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);

        this.renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
        this.renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, java.awt.Color.blue);
        this.renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, true);

        this.renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
        this.renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new java.awt.Color(210, 105, 30));

        this.renderer.setSeriesStroke(2, new BasicStroke(3.0f,
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f,
                new float[] { 2.0f, 6.0f }, 0.0f));

        this.plot.setRenderer(this.renderer);

        final NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) this.plot
                .getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis
        .setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) this.plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat
                .getInstance(Locale.US));

        return chart;
    }

    XYSeries getXYSeries(List<Double> vals, XYSeries series) {

        series.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); ++i) {
            series.add(i + 1, vals.get(i));
        }
        return series;
    }

    void updateChart(List<Double> bestVals, List<Double> medianVals) {

        int size = bestVals.size();

        this.bestValsSeries = getXYSeries(bestVals, this.bestValsSeries);
        this.medianValsSeries = getXYSeries(medianVals,
                this.medianValsSeries);
        this.diffValsSeries.clear();

        if (size > 1) {
            this.diffValsSeries.add(size, bestVals.get(size - 1));
            this.diffValsSeries.add(size, medianVals.get(size - 1));
        }

        this.renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, java.awt.Color.green);
        this.renderer.setSeriesShape(2, this.upTriangleShape);

        if (this.dataset.getItemCount(0) > 0) {
            if (betterThanMedian(this.dataset.getSeries(0),
                    this.dataset.getSeries(1), false)) {
                this.renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, java.awt.Color.red);
                this.renderer.setSeriesShape(2, this.downTriangleShap);
            }
        }

        // Refresh chart
        this.plot.setDataset(this.dataset);
    }
}

private Label                               lblLcloudenvironmentval;
private Label                               lblVMsAtStartVal;
private Label                               reconfigRulesVal;
private Label                               lCostVal;
private Label                               lCostBetterThanVal;
private Label                               lMedianResponseTimesVal;
private Label                               lMedianResponseTimesBetterThanVal;
private Label                               lTimeoutsVal;
private Label                               lTimeoutsBetterThanVal;
private ProgressBar                         currentCDOprogressBar;
private ProgressBar                         overallProgressBar;
private boolean                             optimizationStarted;
private CDOCreationOptimizedAutomaticMethod cdoCreationJob;
private boolean                             saveBestFoundCDO;
private Label                               lblRunning;
private Label                               lblSimulatedCandidates;
private Label                               lRunningVal;
private Label                               lSimulatedCandidatesVal;
private Date                                optimizationStartedDate;
private Group                               grpBestFoundCandidate;
private Label                               lblCurrentCloudDeployment;
private Label                               lblOverallProgress;
private Button                              btnDetailsBestCDO;
private final Color                         swtBlackColor;
private final Color                         swtGreenColor;
private final Color                         swtRedColor;
private MedianBestChart                     costChart;
private MedianBestChart                     responseTimeChart;
private MedianBestChart                     slaViolationsChart;

private final Job                           elapsedTimeUpdaterJob = new Job(
        "Elapsed Time Updater Job") {
    private volatile boolean cancel = false;

    @Override
    protected void canceling() {
        this.cancel = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(
            IProgressMonitor arg0) {

        while (true) {

            Display.getDefault()
            .asyncExec(
                    new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO.this.lRunningVal
                            .setText(Utilities
                                    .getElapsedTime(CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO.this.optimizationStartedDate));

                        }
                    });

            try {
                getThread();
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                if (this.cancel) {
                    return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Utilities
                .logError(e
                        .getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
};
private Composite                           chartParentComposite;
private final AbstractHandler               updateChartsHandler   = new AbstractHandler() {

    @Override
    public Object execute(
            ExecutionEvent ee)
                    throws ExecutionException {

        Map<String, Pair<List<Double>, List<Double>>> applicationContext = (Map<String, Pair<List<Double>, List<Double>>>) ee
                .getApplicationContext();

        final Pair<List<Double>, List<Double>> costsBestAndMedianVals = applicationContext
                .get(org.cloudmig.cloudmigxpress.activity.generation.transformation.ga.Messages.CDOEvaluator_lowCostObjective);
        final Pair<List<Double>, List<Double>> responseTimesBestAndMedianVals = applicationContext
                .get(org.cloudmig.cloudmigxpress.activity.generation.transformation.ga.Messages.CDOEvaluator_lowResponseTimesObjective);
        final Pair<List<Double>, List<Double>> nrTimeoutsBestAndMedianVals = applicationContext
                .get(org.cloudmig.cloudmigxpress.activity.generation.transformation.ga.Messages.CDOEvaluator_lowNrSLAViolationsObjective);

        Display.getDefault()
        .asyncExec(
                new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateCharts(
                                costsBestAndMedianVals,
                                responseTimesBestAndMedianVals,
                                nrTimeoutsBestAndMedianVals);

                    }
                });
        return null;
    }
};

/**
 * Create the wizard.
 */
public CloudDeploymentOptionsCreationWizardPage3ACO() {
    super("wizardPage");
    setImageDescriptor(ResourceManager
            .getPluginImageDescriptor("org.cloudmig.cloudmigxpress",
                    "icons/iconfinder_com_1327065738_question-type-one-correct.png"));
    setTitle("Compute Best Suited Cloud Deployment Option");
    setDescription("Step 3 of 3 - Run the cloud deployment optimization process");
    this.optimizationStarted = false;
    this.saveBestFoundCDO = true;

    this.swtBlackColor = SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK);
    this.swtGreenColor = SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN);
    this.swtRedColor = SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
}
```

---

I have swt components in my code which I have mentioned here.This is swt gui from where user can select inputs from GUI and perform job.I want to unit test that job and measure performance.But I have no idea how to take input from GUI and give  it to jmeter.Or can we bind jmeter code into existing API without writing jmetersmpler.

I have two question in my mind that i want to share with you: 
1)Can Jmeter support swt GUI testing?If yes than can you provide simple demo
2)How to implement jmeter in swt GUI with existing code  and how to test them.

Comment: You might be better off looking at [SWTBot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot test standalone desktop applications out of the box. Normally load testing of the desktop applications is not required as they are used only by single person and if the application reaction time is ok - you don't need to take any extra steps.

However if your application communicates with the backend server - you might want to test the server to check how does it handle the load from multiple concurrent application instances. In that case here are the options:

- If application uses HTTP or HTTPS to communicate with the backend server - you can capture the requests via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and then replay them
- If other protocol is being used - you can check available [JMeter Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) to see whether protocol is being supported and use the relevant sampler
- There are also options to do some coding via the following Test Elements:

  - if you have JUnit tests - you can reuse and run them in multithreaded manner via [JUnit Request Sampler](http://How%20to%20Use%20JUnit%20With%20JMeter)
  - there is also possibility to use one of scripting languages which comply with [JSR-223](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) specification like javascript, jexl, beanshell, etc.